# Detecting the platform in rpm .spec file

Tags: centos, package, rpm

I have a .spec file to build rpm for Fedora, CentOS and Oracle Linux. I need to install a post-uninstall trigger for the kernel package. To achieve that for Oracle Linux, I need to put something like this in my spec file:

```
%triggerpostun -- kernel-uek
%(cat %{SOURCE1001})
```

On CentOS, the package is called kernel, and on Fedora it is called kernel-core. My question is, how do I specify the trigger in my spec file in a portable way (so that it works on all of these target platforms), without any duplication?

EDIT: Some information about what I have tried - I tried putting the following in my spec file:

```
%if 0%{?fedora}
%triggerpostun -- kernel-core
%else
%if 0%{?ol7}
%triggerpostun -- kernel-uek
%else
%triggerpostun -- kernel
%endif
%endif
%(cat %{SOURCE1006})
```

But on CentOS, this gives me a trigger like this:

```
triggerpostun scriptlet (using /bin/sh) -- kernel-uek
for filename in /boot/*.ksplice-updates*; do
    if [[ -h $filename && ! -e $filename ]]; then
        rm $filename
    fi
done
```

which is wrong because the correct package name on CentOS is kernel.

I am complete noob to packaging, so let me know if you need more context to provide suggestion.

Comment: I don't see it here: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:RPMMacros?rd=Packaging/RPMMacros

Comment: See here: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch10s02.html.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the multiple `%else` are causing problems. I would define the conditions this way:

```
%if 0%{?fedora}
%define kernelpkgname kernel-core
%endif

%if 0%{?ol7}
%define kernelpkgname kernel-uek
%endif

%if 0%{?rhel} >= 6
%define kernelpkgname kernel
%endif
```

Then use `kernelpkgname` variable in the `triggerpostun`.

```
%postun
....

%triggerpostun -- %{kernelpkgname}
cat %{SOURCE1006}
```

Comment: Not to say that your solution is wrong (I did not test it), but in the end I settled for something like `%triggerpostun -- kernel, kernel-core, kernel-uek ...` which does the job since the kernel package names are unique among those distros.